# Izpack Process Panel throwing 'null pointer exception'

Tags: installation, izpack

I'm currently using Izpack v5 and running into an issue with the Processing Panel. Whenever the panel executes I immediately get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "processing thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1090)
> at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
> at com.izforge.izpack.panels.process.ProcessPanelWorker$ExecutableFile.run(ProcessPanelWorker.java:551)
> at com.izforge.izpack.panels.process.ProcessPanelWorker$ProcessingJob.run(ProcessPanelWorker.java:471)
> at com.izforge.izpack.panels.process.ProcessPanelWorker.runJob(ProcessPanelWorker.java:415)
> at com.izforge.izpack.panels.process.ProcessPanelWorker.run(ProcessPanelWorker.java:350)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Here is my Process Panel Spec file:

```xml
<izpack:processing version="5.0"
  xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/processing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/processing http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-processing-5.0.xsd">
  <logfiledir>$INSTALL_PATH</logfiledir>

    <job name="Configure Credentials for User (Windows)">
      <os family="windows" />
      <executefile name="$INSTALL_PATH/cot_nifi/bin/nifi.cmd">
        <arg value="set-single-user-credentials"></arg>
        <arg value="$user"></arg>
        <arg value="$password"></arg>
      </executefile>
    </job>

  ....
  
</izpack:processing>
```

I know the directories/files specified exist when the panel kicks off and I've even tried hard-coding the variable values without success.

I was originally calling these same files from within a Packs section and they worked, but within the Process Panel spec they fail.

For instance...
This worked:

```xml
<pack name="Configure User Credentials" required="yes" hidden="true">
    <description>Applies settings based on user-defined values</description>
    <executable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/cot_nifi/bin/nifi.cmd" type="bin" stage="postinstall" failure ="warn" keep="true" >
         <os family="windows" />
             <args>
                <arg value="set-single-user-credentials"/>
                <arg value="$user"/>
                <arg value="$password"/>
              </args>
   </executable>
</pack>
```

I may be wrong, but this seems like a bug in the Process Panel.